# Looking for old bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration, full-node, mac

I briefly ran a node on my Mac in mid to late 2012/early 2013, but didn't understand it at the time and let it go. Is it possible that I still have bitcoin on my computer from that installation, if so, where would I look?

Comment: Hello, welcome to bitcoin.SE! Did you mine or purchase bitcoin at that time? Simply running a node wouldn’t net you any coins.